# Developing an online word processor while learning

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Right now i'm learning web dev(still in html phase) but i really wonder about something. 
I was googling about how to develop a website like google docs but much much much simpler..thinking something just like notepad..By doing this, i will also learn some new stuff..
Anyways, as i read, i need to know javascript right? Why can't i do it in PHP? 
You'll login, write something, and will save it..that's all..
Can someone please tell me the stuff i need to learn in order to make it possible..
Thank you very much

Comment: tinymce (www.tinymce.com) and cke editor (ckeditor.com) are what most of us use.

Comment: @Macmade that was brutal! The guy has a rating of 6, go easy on him/her

Answer (score 1):

You need JS when you don't want to reload the entire page to run some logic. E.g.

- Check form input without reloading the page
- Pass data to server without reloading the page (also called AJAX)
- Insert data from server into the page without reloading the entire page (also called AJAX)
- Dynamic user interface like [fancy message boxes](http://fancybox.net/) or spoilers

With PHP you can generate the HTML before it get delivered to the browser.

With JS  you can manipulate the HTML while it's displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the fact that you said you are "still in html phase" I am going to assume you have little to no knowledge of javascript and/or PHP

Javascript is a language you use on the computer with the web browser (called the client). Rollover images, form submissions, animations... all these 'cool' stuff are implemented via javascript.

PHP is a language you use on the computer with the actual website (called the server). It generally answers questions that javascript asks it. With javascript you could give it the user name and password, and PHP will check the database to see if it is valid, and return true or false.

Obviously, it makes more sense to design the text editor in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in PHP get the text in POST arg argument and save it to sql DB or even file.

but it is better to use java with AJAX.

read about 
POST arg,using SQL,save files. in PHP.

and AJAX[JavaScript]

Comment: AJAX has nothing to do with Java.